# How to find length of a discontinued line feature

Tags: pyqgis, line, road

I wanted to find the length of features in a road layer. So I go through each feature in the layer and used,

```
line = feature.geometry().asPolyline()
```

to find the points which particular feature is created and then used haversine formula to calculate the length. But there are some features(roads) which are not as continued lines (shown in image-yellow coloured), so the `line` returns an empty list.

Is there any way to find length of those type of features?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could create a new attribute column and calculate the length of each feature from there using:

```
$length
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I have used this code to find the length. http://nathanw.net/2011/02/23/total-length-of-selected-objects-qgis-via-python/                                              def getLength():
 layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
 total = 0
 for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()
        total = total + geom.length()
 return total

print getLength()
But how to convert the length I got in degrees to meters programmatically?

Comment: You need convert change the layer's crs. Then get the length with Nathan's length. Note that with his function you need to have all geometry in the same layer and this layer need to be active.